# Weird pointer to member function syntax

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I understand how to declare the type of a function:

```
typedef void (typedef_void_f)(); // typedef_void_f is void()
using alias_void_f     = void(); // alias_void_f is void()
```

And it can be used to declare function pointers:

```
void function() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

typedef_void_f *a = function; // pointer to void()
alias_void_f   *b = function; // pointer to void()
```

For member function pointers the syntax is slightly more complicated:

```
struct S { void function() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; } };

typedef void (S::*typedef_void_m_f)();
using  alias_void_m_f = void (S::*)();

typedef_void_m_f c = &S::function; // pointer to S void() member function
alias_void_m_f   d = &S::function; // pointer to S void() member function
```

This is my understanding of function pointers in C++ and I thought that it was enough.

But in the [p0172r0 technical paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html) I've found a syntax that I'm not familiar:

```
struct host {
   int function() const;
};

template <typename TYPE>
constexpr bool test(TYPE host::*) { // <---- What is this??
    return is_same_v<TYPE, int() const>;
}

constexpr auto member = &host::function;

test(member);
```

As I understand the code, the `test` function *splits* the type of the function from the type of the object where the function belongs, so in the template `test` function the `TYPE` template parameter would be `void()` but if I try the following:

```
void my_test(void() S::*) {}

my_test(&S::function);
```

I get a bunch of syntax errors:

> ```
> error: variable or field 'my_test' declared void
>  void my_test(void() S::*) {}
>                    ^
> error: expected ')' before 'S'
>  void my_test(void() S::*) {}
>                      ^
> error: 'my_test' was not declared in this scope
>      my_test(&S::function);
> ```

So is obvious that I'm not understanding the p0172r0's `test` function syntax.

Can someone explain the details of the `template <typename TYPE> constexpr bool test(TYPE host::*)` syntax?

Comment: No, I'm not asking what does `T::*` means in template's parameters.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Didn't get it reopened quickly.

Comment: This is not limited to member pointers. If you have `using T = int()` then `T* p` is valid, while `int()* p` is forbidden by the grammar rule.

Comment: @cpplearner yes, as it is already pointed out in the [p0172r0 paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html) I was talking about.

Answer (score 3):

`TYPE host::*` is a pointer to a class data member.  `TYPE` is the type of the class member and `host::*` means pointer to member of `host`.  So `TYPE host::*` accepts a pointer to any of member of `host`

Comment: So why `void my_test(void() S::*)` does not accept a pointer to any `void()` member of `S`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster As far as a know a pointer to a class data member and a pointer to a class member function are to different things.  I have never seen a they syntax you are trying to use in any code I have ever seen.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I have been testing and I don't think C++ allows this.  see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5db4e74c2be52aaf

Comment: I've tested the code of [p0172r0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html) in [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qmhjOsxx3gJP33wz) with gcc 6.0.0.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster That is interesting.  I'll have to dig into it a little later.

Comment: NathanOliver you had the opportunity to take a look at this?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I have but I can't quite figure it out.  I would have to ask an SO question to get some clarification on what I am seeing.  I can give you the information and you can ask it since it is your problem .

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
constexpr void my_test(void (S::*)()) {}
```

That is the correct way to declare a parameter typed pointer to member function of `S` returning `void` with no parameters.

http://ideone.com/EqfYmb

Comment: So if `my_test(void (S::*)())` is the correct way to declare pointer to `void()` member `S`, shouldnt `template <typename TYPE> constexpr bool test(TYPE host::*)` be `template <typename TYPE> constexpr bool test(TYPE (host::*)())`? I don't understand the syntax on [p0172r0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I think it is possible to "split" the type like you say, because of the template deduction rules.